# How Can I Pass Result of Foreach from Controller to View CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

just like my title, how can I pass foreach result from controller to view?
So far I did this:
--Controller.php

```
    $get_url_subkategori = $this->ws_url->GetUrl('SubKategoriRetrieve?KodeKategori='.$param);
    $get_json_subkategori = json_decode(file_get_contents($get_url_subkategori), true);
    foreach($get_json_subkategori['SubKategoris'] as $itemSubKategori){
        $kodeSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['KodeSubKategori'];
        $namaSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Nama'];
        $definisiSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Definisi'];
        $unsurAbstrakSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['UnsurAbstrak'];
        $aliasSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Alias'];

        $data['kodeSubKategori']=$kodeSubKategori;
        $data['namaSubKategori']=$namaSubKategori;
        $data['definisiSubKategori']=$definisiSubKategori;
        $data['unsurAbstrakSubKategori']=($unsurAbstrakSubKategori) ? 'true' : 'false';
        $data['aliasSubKategori']=$aliasSubKategori;
    }

    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('kategori_detail', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
```

Then, in my view:

```
<h3>Sub Kategori</h3>
            <table class="table table-responsive table-inherit">
                <tr>
                    <th>Kode Sub Kategori</th>
                    <th>Nama Kategori</th>
                    <th>Definisi</th>
                    <th>Unsur Abstrak</th>
                    <th>Alias</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach((array)$kodeSubKategori as $itemKodeSubKategori)
                            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori.'</td>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach((array)$namaSubKategori as $itemNamaSubKategori)
                            echo '<td>'.$itemNamaSubKategori.'</td>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach((array)$definisiSubKategori as $itemDefinisiSubKategori)
                            echo '<td>'.$itemDefinisiSubKategori.'</td>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach((array)$unsurAbstrakSubKategori as $itemUnsurAbstrakSubKategori)
                            echo '<td>'.$itemUnsurAbstrakSubKategori.'</td>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach((array)$aliasSubKategori as $itemAliasSubKategori)
                            echo '<td>'.$itemAliasSubKategori.'</td>';
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

It successfully show ONLY THE LAST ONE data. I want to get all data from the result from foreach. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to pass all `$get_json_subkategori['SubKategoris']` array in `data` array to your view:

```
$get_url_subkategori = $this->ws_url->GetUrl('SubKategoriRetrieve?KodeKategori='.$param);
$get_json_subkategori = json_decode(file_get_contents($get_url_subkategori), true);
$data['itemSubKategori'] = $get_json_subkategori['SubKategoris'];

$this->load->view('include/header');
$this->load->view('kategori_detail', $data);
$this->load->view('include/footer');
```

And in your view:

```
   <h3>Sub Kategori</h3>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-inherit">
            <tr>
                <th>Kode Sub Kategori</th>
                <th>Nama Kategori</th>
                <th>Definisi</th>
                <th>Unsur Abstrak</th>
                <th>Alias</th>
            </tr>
             <?php foreach($itemSubKategori as $rowSubKategori): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['kodeSubKategori'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['namaSubKategori'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['definisiSubKategori'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['definisiSubKategori'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['unsurAbstrakSubKategori'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowSubKategori['aliasSubKategori'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: If it is helped, do not forget to accept the answer ;) @gultomicro

Answer (score 1):

Because you data array override each time that's y you get only last value every time.

You need to create your array with auto incremented value

```
$i=0;
foreach($get_json_subkategori['SubKategoris'] as $itemSubKategori){
        $kodeSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['KodeSubKategori'];
        $namaSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Nama'];
        $definisiSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Definisi'];
        $unsurAbstrakSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['UnsurAbstrak'];
        $aliasSubKategori = $itemSubKategori['Alias'];

        $data[$i]['kodeSubKategori']=$kodeSubKategori;
        $data[$i]['namaSubKategori']=$namaSubKategori;
        $data[$i]['definisiSubKategori']=$definisiSubKategori;
        $data[$i]['unsurAbstrakSubKategori']=($unsurAbstrakSubKategori) ? 'true' : 'false';
        $data[$i]['aliasSubKategori']=$aliasSubKategori;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response. But, is my code on view right? It is not show anything

Comment: `print_r($kodeSubKategori)` in your view and check the result of it

Comment: Great, I can see that result now @Saty

Comment: Glad to know you get data in your view

Answer (score 0):

> **Pass data in one array. and you can catch all in view at one `foreach` llop**

Use this

**In Controller**

```
$get_url_subkategori = $this->ws_url->GetUrl('SubKategoriRetrieve?KodeKategori='.$param);
$get_json_subkategori = json_decode(file_get_contents($get_url_subkategori), true);


$data['itemKodeSubKategori']    =   $get_json_subkategori;

$this->load->view('include/header');
$this->load->view('kategori_detail', $data);
$this->load->view('include/footer');
```

**In View**

```
<tr>
    <?php
        foreach($kodeSubKategori as $itemKodeSubKategori)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori['KodeSubKategori'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori['Nama'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori['Definisi'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori['UnsurAbstrak'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$itemKodeSubKategori['Alias'].'</td>';
        }
    ?>       
</tr>
```